# How i can make my code secure from SQL Injection

Tags: php, sql-injection

I know i am not secure when i am using this code so anything i can add in my code?

I have tried my self sql injection they are somewhere working but not much as i dont have much knowledge about sql injection. but as hacker are more smart so they can really hack my website.

Url looks like this :

```
http://example.com/profile.php?userID=1
```

**php**

```
$userID = $_GET['userID'];
$userID = mysql_real_escape_string($userID);
$CheckQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE id='$userID'");

$CheckNumber = mysql_num_rows($CheckQuery);
if ($CheckNumber !== 1)
{
    header("Location: tos.php");
}
```

I tried:

```
http://example.com/profile.php?userID=1'
```

which hide many things on site.

when i tried

```
http://example.com/profile.php?userID=1' UNION SELECT * FROM tbl_user; with havij it was hacked
```

Thanks :|

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1920232

Comment: Not duplicate i checked it

Comment: What if you try `http://example.com/profile.php?userID=0` - will it "hide many things" too?

Answer (score 0):

use mysqli::prepare or at least sprintf

```
mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE id='%d'", $userID);

$db = new mysqli(<database connection info here>);

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE id='?'");
$stmt->bind_param("id", $userID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use mysql_* functionality at all.
Use PDO or mysqli.

http://php.net/PDO
http://php.net/mysqli

PDO will escape your data for you.

But for your current code:

```
$userID = $_GET['userID'];
$userID = mysql_real_escape_string($userID);

if(ctype_digit($userID))
{
    $CheckQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE id='$userID'");

    $CheckNumber = mysql_num_rows($CheckQuery);
    if ($CheckNumber !== 1)
    {
        header("Location: tos.php");
    }
} else {
    // THE USER ID IS NOT ALL NUMBERS, CREATE AN ERROR
}
```

Comment: Its a old website and if i try to change codes it will take more then month :(

Comment: There's no substitute for good security. Unfortunately, if your database gets hacked because the security used is poor, your company / your person is likely to get into trouble for it.

Comment: yes so true. its an online game

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Comment: Why the downvote? There isn't a parse error in the code mentioned above. I only added 1 meaningful line of code, which was to ensure the userID value is a number. `if(ctype_digit($userID))...`

Answer (score 0):

> I know i am not secure when i am using this code

This statement is wrong.
As a matter of fact, **this very code is pretty secure.**

And none of the codes you provided below would do any harm. Why do you think it is not secure?

This way is *not recommended*, yes. And the way you are using to format your queries *may* lead to injection for some other query. But the present code is perfectly secure.

As long as you are enclosing every variable in quotes **and** escape special chars in it - it is safe to be put into query.
**Only if you omit one these two rules** (i.e. escape but don't quote or quote but don't escape) - you are in sure danger. But as long as you're following both, you're safe.

The only reason for "hacking" I can guess of is a single quote used in **HTML context**. In some circumstances it can "hide many things on the page". But for the SQL, with the code you posted here, it's **harmless**

Look, out of this link

```
http://example.com/profile.php?userID=1'
```

your code will produce such a query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE id='1\''
```

which is quite **legit** for mysql and will even **return a record** for id=1, as it will cast `1'` to `1` and find the record. This is why there is no redirect to tos.php.

So, the problem is somewhere else.

- either there is a code that does not follow the rules I posted above
- or this problem is unrelated to SQL at all - so, you are barking wrong tree and thus **still keep whatever vulnerability open**

Most likely you have to echo your values out

Comment: atleast it should take them to tos.php when they use : http://example.com/profile.php?userID=1'

Comment: i tried it myself. with havij. and it was hacked

Comment: ok it may be because i filled correct table name

Comment: well, you tried it with some **other** code then.

Comment: yes trying out every possible things i know

Answer (score -1):

u can try `type casting` the value

```
<?php


$CheckQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE id='".(int)$userID."'");

?>
```

Comment: No, this wont work this way! This way `(int)` will just be part of the query string. What you could try is `$userID = (int)$userID;` before doing the query string line.

Comment: check the query now..